# how to Mock scrollBy function Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hello i have a scrollBar that i want to test with jest+enzyme ! i realised that i have to mock the function first
i checked few tutorials but it's not working, the function is always not defined
this is what i tried :

```js
it('One step scroll working', function () {
     const scrollBySpy = jest.fn()
     global.document.scrollBy = scrollBySpy;
     wrapper.find('Button').at(1).prop('onDoubleClick')()
     expect(scrollBySpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

the function we call with `simulate('click')`

```js
scrollToTheEnd = (direction: string) => {
    if (direction !== 'right' && direction !== 'left') return
    let walk = direction === 'right' ? 3000 : -3000
    const slider: HTMLElement = this.state.scrollRef.current;
    slider.scrollBy(walk, 0)
}
```

I have this error inside the function `scrollToTheEnd`

> TypeError: slider.scrollBy is not a function

Any idea ?

Comment: can you show more code? it's quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a unit test solution:

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export interface ISomeComponentState {
  direction: string;
  scrollRef: {
    current: HTMLElement | null;
  };
}

class SomeComponent extends Component<any, ISomeComponentState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      direction: 'right',
      scrollRef: {
        current: null
      }
    };
  }
  scrollToTheEnd = (direction: string) => {
    if (direction !== 'right' && direction !== 'left') return;
    let walk = direction === 'right' ? 3000 : -3000;
    const slider: HTMLElement = this.state.scrollRef.current as HTMLElement;
    slider.scrollBy(walk, 0);
  };

  render() {
    return <button onDoubleClick={() => this.scrollToTheEnd(this.state.direction)}>scroll to the end</button>;
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`index.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import SomeComponent, { ISomeComponentState } from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  test('should scroll to the end', () => {
    const mCurrent = document.createElement('div');
    mCurrent.scrollBy = jest.fn();
    const mState: ISomeComponentState = { direction: 'right', scrollRef: { current: mCurrent } };
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent></SomeComponent>);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('scroll to the end');
    wrapper.setState(mState);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('doubleClick');
    expect(mCurrent.scrollBy).toBeCalledWith(3000, 0);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56639450/index.spec.tsx (7.287s)
  SomeComponent
    ✓ should scroll to the end (15ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |    94.12 |     62.5 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |    94.12 |     62.5 |      100 |      100 |             21,22 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.459s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56639450